# How to calculate the norm of quternion in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, quaternions

How can I calculate the norm of quaternion in matlab?

I tried this example

```
a = [1 4 4 -4];
norm = quatnorm(a)
```

My expected output is 7 but matlab returns 49.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try some other examples and see if your expected answer is always the square root of the Matlab answer.

Comment: The documentation for [`quatnorm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/quatnorm.html) doesn't indicate what kind of norm is used, but the [Simulink version](http://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/quaternionnorm.html) defines it without the `sqrt`. No idea why. I don't have the Aerospace toolbox, but from what I've seen of it, it seems to have some rather poor design choices.

Comment: And one thing you are doing wrong is overwriting the actual `norm` function by creating a variable of the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dan points out, using the native implementation, you are probably getting the square of the formal norm definition. For some reason `quatnorm` returns the square, after estimating the Euclidean norm (square root of sum of squares).

```
q = [1 4 4 -4];
```

**MATLAB`quatnorm`:**

```
for index = size(q, 1):-1:1
    qnorm(index,:) = norm(q(index,:), 2);
end    
qout = qnorm.*qnorm;
```

**Alternative (for vectors):**

```
sqrt(q*q')
```

This is equivalent to getting `sqrt(quatnorm(q))`. As you will note above, `quatnorm` is also adapted to estimate norms for quaternions stored in successive matrix rows (estimates the norm of each row and then squares)

**Alternative (for matrices N x 4):**

```
Q = [q; 2*q]; % example

sqrt(diag(Q*Q'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either take square root of the returned number, or you can use function quatmod(q) instead, which calculates the proper Euclidean norm (modulus) of the complex number by not taking square of it.